# Find combination(s) sum of element(s) in array whose sum equal to a given number

Tags: php, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm: Extract subset based on property sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807855/algorithm-extract-subset-based-on-property-sum)

in the simple case we have an array:

{6, 1, 3, 11, 2, 5,12}

and we want to know all combinations the sum of elements contained in that array to getting **12**.

in this case we will get **four** combinations:

- 12
- 1 + 11
- 6 + 5 + 1
- 1 + 3 + 2 + 6

so, how can we do this in BASIC or PHP?. maybe pseudo-code first  ;-).

I've been looking but there just got a combination with a predetermined number of elements.

Comment: Yes, pseudo code first please.

Comment: N=2^set_size;  for (i=0;i<N;i++) { sum=0; for (k=0;k<set_size;k++) if (i & (1<<k)) sum+= element[k]; if (sum==target_sum) print_the_elements_pointed_by_bit_vector(i) }  In this case there are 2^7 = 128 combinations to pick from; and all of them have to be tested (perhaps we could rule out all values > target_sum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard). Even determining if there is ANY subset of the problem that sums to the desired number is NP-Hard (known as the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)), and there is no known polynomial solution to it.

Thus, you should look for an exponantial solution, such as a backtracking one - generate all possible combinations, and check if they are valid.

You can use trimming to get your search faster (for example, if you generate a partial subset of sum 13, no need to check other subsets which are supersets of this subset, since they will definetly won't lead to a solution.

pseudo code:

```
findValidSubsets(sum,arr,idx,currSolution):
   if (sum == 0):
       print currSolution
   if (sum < 0): //trim the search, it won't be succesful
       return
   //one possibility: don't take the current candidate
   findPermutations(sum,arr,idx+1,currSolution) 

   //second poassibility: take the current candidate
   currSolution.add(arr[idx])
   findPermutations(sum-arr[idx],arr,idx+1,currSolution)

   //clean up before returning: 
   currSolution.removeLast()
```

Complexity is `O(2^n)` - need to generate at worst case all 2^n possible subsets

Invoke with `findValidSubsets(desiredSum,myArray,0,[])`, where `[]` is an empty initial list

Comment: trimming only works if there aren't negative numbers.  if there are, sort first, then you can use (a more generic) trimming.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @KarolyHorvath - both for the positives only clarification and for the improvement suggestion. To Bakti and future readers: to avoid trimming, just remove the `if(sum<0) return` part.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
echo "<pre>";

$sum = 12 ; //SUM
$array = array(6,1,3,11,2,5,12);
$list = array();

# Extract All Unique Conbinations
extractList($array, $list);

#Filter By SUM = $sum
$list = array_filter($list,function($var) use ($sum) { return(array_sum($var) == $sum);});

#Return Output
var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      3 => string '3' (length=1)
      4 => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => string '6' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '11' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array
      1 => string '12' (length=2)
```

Functions Used

```
function extractList($array, &$list, $temp = array()) {
    if (count($temp) > 0 && ! in_array($temp, $list))
        $list[] = $temp;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i ++) {
        $copy = $array;
        $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
        if (sizeof($copy) > 0) {
            $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
            sort($add);
            extractList($copy, $list, $add);
        } else {
            $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
            sort($add);
            if (! in_array($temp, $list)) {
                $list[] = $add;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't want to offend you, but this code is horribly ugly...

Comment: @Karoly Horvath  am sure you can clean it up ..... :)

Comment: Just just works!  It also seems to be a lot shorter and easier than any other solution I found!  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

using dynamic programming you can express solution as

```
solver(sum,start_index)
     stop_condition_here_when sum <= 0

     r=0
     for  i=start_index ; i < last_iddex :
            r += solver(sum - array[i],i+1)
            r += solver(sum ,i+1)
     return r
```

And adding extra memositaion would also speedup this program

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the length of the set. In each step, check all subsets of length `k`:

```
for k = 1 to size(input):
    foreach permutation p of length k:
        if sum(p) == 12:
            bam!
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to iterate over all *permutations* there are `k!` of those for each k, you need to iterate over all subsets, there are 'only' `2^n` of those.

Comment: Correction: There are `Choose(n,k)*k! = n!/(n-k)!` possible permutations for each `k`.