# PHP: coin change puzzle

Tags: php, coin-change

I'm working on Advent of Code as a way to practice TDD and learn PHPSpec. I'm stuck on Day 17, which is essentially the coin change puzzle.

> The elves bought too much eggnog again - 150 liters this time. To fit it all into your refrigerator, you'll need to move it into smaller containers. You take an inventory of the capacities of the available containers.
>
> For example, suppose you have containers of size 20, 15, 10, 5, and 5 liters. If you need to store 25 liters, there are four ways to do it:
>
> - 15 and 10
> - 20 and 5 (the first 5)
> - 20 and 5 (the second 5)
> - 15, 5, and 5
>
> Filling all containers entirely, how many different combinations of containers can exactly fit all 150 liters of eggnog?

Here's my code. I wrote a test using the examples above. The `combinations` method should return `4` per the example, but it returns 3. It doesn't seem to be able to handle the fact that there's more than one container of size 5 litres.

Any suggestions please?

```
<?php

namespace Day17;

class Calculator
{
    private $containers = [];

    public function combinations($total, array $containers)
    {
        $combinations = $this->iterate($total, $containers);
        return count($combinations);
    }

    /**
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837431/find-combinations-sum-of-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number
     *
     * @param $array
     * @param array $combinations
     * @param array $temp
     * @return array
     */
    private function iterate($sum, $array, $combinations = [], $temp = [])
    {
        if (count($temp) && !in_array($temp, $combinations)) {
            $combinations[] = $temp;
        }

        $count = count($array);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

            $copy = $array;
            $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);

            if (count($copy) > 0) {

                $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
                sort($add);
                $combinations = $this->iterate($sum, $copy, $combinations, $add);

            } else {

                $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
                sort($add);
                if (array_sum($combinations) == $sum) {
                    $combinations[] = $add;
                }
            }
        }

        return array_filter($combinations, function ($combination) use ($sum) {
            return array_sum($combination) == $sum;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: One principle in TDD is having bite-sized pieces of code that are easy to test. Maybe you should break this into smaller pieces to narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Array Indices of the Available Containers as the combination values.