# Find combination of numbers such that their addition is closest to a number?

Tags: r, excel

I have a column named Orders. I want to cluster them into groups in such a way sum of orders in a cluster is close to 300. Below is the input.

```
**Orders**
100
198
50
40
215
296
```

The output should look like

```
Orders  Group
100     1
198     1
50      2
40      2
215     2
296     3
```

This is just a sample data. In Real the data is pretty huge. Can this be done using R.

Comment: try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837431/find-combinations-sum-of-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number

Answer (score 2):

## Results

Below are functions that tackle the problem, firstly though here are the results

```
find_grouping(orders, 300L)
#      orders group
# [1,]    100     1
# [2,]    198     1
# [3,]     50     2
# [4,]     40     2
# [5,]    215     2
# [6,]    296     3

allocate_groups(orders, 300L, 3L)    # third argument <-> max. num. of groups
#      orders group
# [1,]    100     3
# [2,]    198     3
# [3,]     50     2
# [4,]     40     2
# [5,]    215     2
# [6,]    296     1 

# bigger vector
set.seed(123)
orders <- sample(1:300, 15)
find_grouping(orders, 300L)
#       orders group
#  [1,]     87     2
#  [2,]    236     2
#  [3,]    122     3
#  [4,]    263     4
#  [5,]    279     5
#  [6,]     14     9
#  [7,]    156     6
#  [8,]    262     7
#  [9,]    162     8
# [10,]    133     8
# [11,]    278     9
# [12,]    132    10
# [13,]    196     1
# [14,]    165    10
# [15,]     30     7
allocate_groups(orders, 300L, 3L)
#       orders group
#  [1,]     87     1
#  [2,]    236     2
#  [3,]    122     3
#  [4,]    263     3
#  [5,]    279     1
#  [6,]     14     2
#  [7,]    156     3
#  [8,]    262     3
#  [9,]    162     2
# [10,]    133     1
# [11,]    278     2
# [12,]    132     2
# [13,]    196     1
# [14,]    165     1
# [15,]     30     3
```

with the data `orders = c(100L, 198L, 50L, 40L, 215L, 296L)`.

---

## Edit: New Function

Considering the added constraint of wanting to specify the number of groups, here comes a new function

```
create_groups <- function (orders, num, group_num) {
  orders
  groups <- rep(list(NA_integer_), group_num)
  for (k in sort(orders, decreasing = TRUE)) {
    sums <- vapply(1:group_num, function (s) as.integer(sum(groups[[s]], na.rm = TRUE)), integer(1))
    index <- ifelse(any(sums + k <= num), which(sums + k <= num)[which.min(abs(sums[which(sums + k <= num)]+k - num))], NA_integer_)
    index <- ifelse(is.na(index), which.min(sums), index)
    groups[[index]] <- append(groups[[index]],k)
    groups[[index]] <- groups[[index]][!is.na(groups[[index]])]
  }
  groups
}
allocate_groups <- function (orders, num, group_num) {
  groups <- create_groups(orders, num, group_num)
  g <- rep(seq_along(groups), sapply(groups, length))
  out <- cbind(orders, group = g[match(orders, unlist(groups))])
  out
}
# results above
```

The added constraint actually makes the problem somewhat simpler: There are (at most) `n` drawers that we want to fill with `orders` and any total sum should be as close to `num` as possible.

---

## The Function

Here is the full code of the function

```
find_grouping <- function (orders, num) {
    combs2 <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(orders, 2L, constraintFun = 'sum')
    combs2 <- cbind.data.frame(combs2,close=abs(num - combs2[,3]))
    out <- integer(length(orders))
    skip <- NA_integer_
    group <- 1L
    for (k in seq_along(out)) {
      val1 <- orders[k]
      if (val1 %in% skip) next
      ind1 <- (.subset2(combs2,1L) == val1) | (.subset2(combs2,2L) == val1)  
      ind2 <- (which.min(.subset2(combs2, 4L)[ind1]))
      ind3 <- which(ind1)[ind2]
      val2 <- .subset2(combs2, 3L)[ind3]
      if (abs(num-val1) <= abs(num-val2)) {
        out[k] <- group
        group  <- group + 1L
        next
      }
      intList <- as.integer(combs2[ind3,1:2])
      ordersRemain <- setdiff(orders, intList)
      if (abs(num-val2) <= abs(num-val2-min(ordersRemain))) {
        skip <- c(skip, intList)
        out[orders %in% intList] <- group
        group <- group + 1
        next
      }
      val3 <- val2
      cond <- FALSE
      while (!cond) {
        toAdd <- which.min(abs(num - (val2 + ordersRemain)))
        val3 <- val3 + ordersRemain[toAdd]
        intList <- c(intList, ordersRemain[toAdd])
        ordersRemain <- ordersRemain[-toAdd]
        cond <- abs(num-val3) <= abs(num-val2-min(ordersRemain))
      }
      skip <- c(skip, intList)
      out[orders %in% intList] <- group
      group <- group + 1
    }
    cbind(orders,group=out)
}
```

---

## Explanation

The first step was to generate all combinations (of 2) of orders 
 using `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` (it is a rather fast method)

```
# num
combs <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(orders, 2L, constraintFun = 'sum')
combs <- cbind.data.frame(combs,close=abs(num - combs[,3])) # check how far from num are the combinations
#      1   2   3 close
# 1  100 198 298     2
# 2  100  50 150   150
# 3  100  40 140   160
# 4  100 215 315    15
# ...
```

From here on now there are several approaches. I opted for a loop where in each iteration I find the best combinations (i.e. closest to `num`) for the current value `orders[k]`, remember then given combination (e.g. `100;198`) and assign the combination a `group` value.

Comment: this works, but it divides the data into unlimited group in real data. Can we keep a check on the group i.e in this case say, if we want max 3 groups to be made.

Comment: @NitinKansal See the edit for the added constraint.

Comment: this works and divides the data, but the issue is I want that all groups should almost have equal number of orders. So say there are 8323 total orders that has to be divided among 26 teams then each team shall get approx 320 orders. I have a sample order data:

Orders: 236,233,170,127,129,102,115,142,155,144,135,144,138,86,153,99,107,111,120,100,106,175,101,116,159,111,137,152,158,198,122,163,133,146,146,111,127,82,95,174,78,155,91,154,95,145,172,102,45,89,85,57,72,84,35,65,90,72,61,95,96,125,51,49,5,8,23,26,81,14,39,35,24,57,95,136,53,53,53

Answer (score 0):

This solves a variant of the problem you posed in which the group sum may not exceed the target sum.

```
library(BBmisc); library(dplyr);
bin.capacity <- 305
df <- data.frame(Orders = c(100,198,50,40,215,296)) %>%
  mutate(Group = BBmisc::binPack(Orders,bin.capacity))
> df
  Orders Group
1    100     3
2    198     3
3     50     2
4     40     2
5    215     2
6    296     1
```

for bin.capacity = 300:

```
> df
  Orders Group
1    100     3
2    198     3
3     50     2
4     40     4
5    215     2
6    296     1
```